# Incorrect Data while loading JDBC table in Spark SQL

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mariadb

I created a table "students" in MariaDB containing 2 rows of data:

```
id name      marks
-- --------- -----
1  saptarshi 98
2  sagar     95
```

I want to use JDBC to read this table in spark-sql, so I opened up spark-shell and executed the following commands:

```
spark-shell --jars mariadb-java-client-1.5.0-RC1.jar
scala> val url = "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sparkdb"
scala> val driver = "org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver"
scala> val df = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", url).option("driver", driver).option("dbtable", "students").option("user", "cloudera").option("password", "cloudera").load()

scala> df.printSchema
root
|-- id: integer (nullable = false)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- marks: integer (nullable = true)
```

The schema has been loaded correctly, so I wanted to display the 'name' column.

```
scala> df.select("name").show
+----+
|name|
+----+
|name|
|name|
+----+
```

Instead of displaying the rows, it displayed the column name in both the records.

Why am I not getting correct results? Can anyone help me here.

Comment: Thanks Jim for formatting the text

Comment: Sounds like it generated `SELECT "name" ...` instead of `SELECT \`name\` ...`.

Comment: I tried another approach using Column object but same result :(

`scala> df.select($"name").show`
`+----+`
`|name|`
`+----+`
`|name|`
`|name|`
`+----+`

`scala> df.select($"name").show`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know scala/spark syntax, or how it converts to SQL.

Comment: Thats Ok Rick. Your suggestion was definitely worth trying

Comment: If Rick's suspicion is correct, then changing the url to "jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/sparkdb?sessionVariables=sql_mode='ANSI_QUOTES'" can be worth trying. With ANSI_QUOTES on, "name" is considered identified rather than string "name". http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this with other Databases like Oracle and Derby. They produce correct results. This problem appears only for MariaDB.